# Enabling Instruction Cache Prefetching in GEM5

Tags: gem5

I noticed that in the GEM5 full system provided by ARM (`fs.py`), the HPI CPU instruction cache does not use a prefetcher. The source code specifically states `# No prefetcher, this is handled by the core` (`HPI.py`).

I tried adding a prefetcher to the ICache to look into this issue. The `config.ini` output showed that the prefetcher was indeed included in the system, but examining `stats.txt` I saw that it did not issue any prefetch requests. I also spent some time reading through the core source code, but could not identify any component that seemed to handle instruction prefetching.

I was wondering why this is. I can think of scenarios where instruction prefetching could benefit the CPU performance, and am not aware of a technical problem implementing it. This is especially confusing to me since it seems the system was built to allow using instruction prefetching: the configuration scripts allow setting a prefetcher for the ICache from the command line, the `ICache` class is derived from `Cache` and so can incorporate a prefetcher, and prefetchers in GEM5 have a `on_inst` property which supposedly controls instruction prefetching.

Can anyone explain the logic behind this, and possibly suggest ways to enable prefetching for the instruction cache?

Comment: Not sure about this, but just to check, you tried an option such as `--l1i-hwp-type` and it didn't seem to have any effect is that it? Also I would just try looking at the C cache source as well.

Comment: Yes and no. It had the expected effect of adding the `prefetcher` attribute to the `icache` object, but the prefetcher did not issue any hardware prefetch requests according to `stats.txt`, so had no practical effect.
Looking at the C source code is what got me wondering about this - the `icache` and `dcache` objects are instances of the same SimObject, but while `dcache` prefetching is prevalent, `icache` prefetching seems to have no effect at all.